# How can I limit a textbox to have less than 3 commas in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example we have a textbox which is for tags for a blog. What I want is I want to limit number of tags to be limited. 
**For instance, "web hosting,php,windows8".** 
When the user tries to type another one to textbox which he will start with comma, the textbox won't let him write it.

Comment: if you want me to write the code for ya i will not, if you want to get the concept i will help you, try to catch the keyup events and filter the comma when it reachs the limit prevent any other comma insertions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `keypress` handler, capture the `event` object and do;

```
if (event.which == 44 && $(this).val().split(",").length > 2) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

See it in action here; http://jsfiddle.net/5L7mU/

Answer (score 2):

We can split this problem into 3 smaller problems.

First, we need a way to stop the user from writing stuff into the textbox. When you hook a callback on `keypress`, the event passed has a method called `preventDefault` which should do the job. So to block all input:

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Now, to check how many comas there already are in the textbox, we can use regex. The `match` function will return `null` instead of an empty array if there are no matches so we gotta check for that.

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    var matches = $(this).val().match(/,/g);
    var count = 0;
    if (matches)
        count = matches.length;
    console.log(count);
});
```

Finally, we need to be able to check if the user typed in a coma. The `event` objectwill have a property called `which` that contains the key code of the character entered. With a little bit of exploring, you can find out that the key code for coma is 44.

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 44)
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

So if we put it all together:

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    var matches = $(this).val().match(/,/g);
    var count = 0;
    if (matches)
        count = matches.length;

    if (count >= 2 && event.which == 44)
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4wn5W/

Comment: Good solutin with step by step explanation. Now I know how this works very well. Thank you.

Comment: @SNaRe No problem. Don't forget to use the arrows next to the answers to thank people for their contributions and the checkmark to mark the answer that you found helped you most resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textbox').keypress(function(e){
        var text = $(this).val();
        if(text.split(',').length>3){
             return false;
        }else if(e.which==44&&text.split(',').length>2){
           return false
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L4X4C/